# I would like in relation with the user, access its forecasts and see if the forecast exists for the match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

The goal is to hide a match on the front side if the user has already forecasted the match.
I'm showing all the matches if they have not started yet and I would like to show it or not if the user has already forecasted on it.
For this I'm using :

```
@matches.each do |match|
if Time.parse(match.kick_off) > Time.now && ??
```

But then when I use current_user.forecasts, I access all the forecasts of the user but then I can't compare it with the match and see if the forecast exists for a special match.

```
class Match < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :forecasts
  has_many :season_matchs
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :player_seasons
  has_many :forecasts, through: :player_seasons
end
```

```
class Forecast < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player_season
  belongs_to :match
end
```

Comment: What is the `SeasonMatch` model?

Comment: Hello, it represents le the matches from the current season

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question by myself.
For those who are interested, I used .find_by

```
current_user.forecasts.find_by(match_id: match.id).nil?
```